# Python ucs-4/ucs-2 incompatibility

Tags: python, python-2.7, mpi4py, ucs2, ucs-4

I got incompatibility issue trying to link my Python interpreter(compiled with UCS-4) with the local MPICH2 library(compiled with UCS-2). the error message is shown as below:

***ImportError: /home/densitymatrix4/a/gu163/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpi4py/MPI.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeUTF8***

I wonder if there are any ways to solve this problem other than re-installing a UCS-2 python interpreter(since I don't have administrative privilege of the server). Such as find a MPI library based on UCS-4 ?

Or does anyone have some suggestions regarding to the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Hi Rob, I am using a linux version 2.6.32, Red Hat 4.4.7-17.

Comment: For Python 2, I don't think there's any way around the requirement of matching the build of a library with the build of Python itself. Python 3.3 and later might be more forgiving, since they do away with the distinction altogether in their internal storage of Unicode strings.